# Бесконечный цикл while Ответ должен быть 14888 но в итоге получается бесконечный цикл,

Tags: python

Бесконечный цикл в задании : Ниже на пяти языках программирования записан алгоритм. Получив на вход число x, этот алгоритм печатает числа: a и b. Укажите наименьшее положительное пятизначное число x, при котором после выполнения алгоритма будет напечатано сначала 4, а потом 2. Код :

```
    for i in range (1,1000000):
       a = 0
       b = 0
       x = i
       while x > 0:
           y = x % 10
           if y > 3:
               a = a+1
           if y < 8:
                b = b+1
           x = x // 10
       print(a, b, i)
```

Ответ должен быть 14888 но в итоге получается бесконечный цикл,

Comment: Вы уверены, что бесконечный? Может, вы просто не дождались его завершения?

Comment: На моём телефоне этот код выполняется за 30 секунд

Comment: Тогда получается 4 2 4488

Comment: Какой код вы написали, такой результат и получается

Answer (score 1):

Ну так поставьте проверку на это условие в конце цикла:

```
       if a==4 and b==2 and i>9999:
           print(a, b, i)
           break
```